# Java: File Directory and Replacing issue

Tags: java

I'm making a program in which user enter values in text fields then it generates a directory and text file. But issue is when I run the program it generates directory also when the program catch an exception then it's create a text file. I only want that happen on user enter values. Then it makes directory and text file.

Second:
When text file is generated then on again program runs text file is replaced with new one. Old one is replaced. I want to make new text file on again program run like open1.txt & open2.txt

Code:

```
public class V extends JFrame{

    private JTextField t1;
    private JTextField t2;
    private JButton b1;

    public V(){
        File file1 = new File("C:\\Users\\hamel\\Desktop\\z");
        file1.mkdirs();
        File file2 = new File("C:\\Users\\hamel\\Desktop\\z\\open.txt");

        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        t1=new JTextField();
        t1.setBounds(30,26,47,28);
        getContentPane().add(t1);

        t2=new JTextField();
        t2.setBounds(103,26,47,28);
        getContentPane().add(t2);

        b1=new JButton("Click");
        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                String w = t1.getText();
                String x = t2.getText();
                int i,j ,k;

                try{
                    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file2);
                    i = Integer.parseInt(w);

                    k = Integer.parseInt(x);
                    pw.println("You Enter in Text Field 1:"+i);

                    pw.println("You Enter in Text Field 2:"+k);
                    pw.close();
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
                }
            }
        });

        b1.setBounds(235,26,87,28);
        getContentPane().add(b1);

        setSize(400,400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);   
    }

}
```

Main:

```
public class Open_2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        V next = new V();   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For your first problem:**

You are creating the directory even before your GUI is layedout. Hence it is always created. If you don't want the directory and file to be created if there is an exception move your `file1.mkdirs();` to the action listener and modify your try block to something like this.

```
try {
    i = Integer.parseInt(w);
    k = Integer.parseInt(x);

    file1.mkdirs();
    File file2 = File.createTempFile("open", ".txt", file1);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file2);

    pw.println("You Enter in Text Field 1:"+i);

    pw.println("You Enter in Text Field 2:"+k);
    pw.close();
}
```

**For your second problem:**

If you want a new file to be created everytime starting with the name `open` but not necessarily `open1` and `open2` and so on, you can use

`File file2 = File.createTempFile("open", ".txt", file1)` after your `file1.mkdirs()` command.

But remember, createTempFile command will generate a random name starting with `open` and ending with `.txt` but not necessarily `open1.txt`, `open2.txt` and so on.

Comment: first problem is solve.can you make a code of second problem.

Comment: The answer already gives an option for the second problem also... Are you not satisfied with that???

Comment: try{
   PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file2);
     i = Integer.parseInt(w);
    
        k = Integer.parseInt(x);
        file1.mkdirs(); it gives exception error when button is clicked

Comment: That's because the directory is not yet created when you invoke PrintWriter. Check the answer, it invokes the PrintWriter after creating the directory.

Comment: I have updated the answer for your second question also... But remember the created files wont be `open1.txt`, `open2.txt` and so on... But will be random and unique starting with `open` and ending with `.txt`.

Comment: your second question answer create a temporary file of txt file not make new txt file.

Comment: There is no concept of temporary file in java... The API is named as such... But it just creates a normal file like any other command... Only that the naming is different...